# Getting the age of cached data downloaded by WebClient

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm using WebClient in a WP7 app to download some data from a server that I have no control over. The data seems to get cached by the system - once the data is downloaded from the server, a cached copy will be served afterwards for a while. I have no problems with this caching behaviour (it's actually ideal for me) but I would like to indicate to the user that the data they're viewing may be out of date.

I'm looking for some property or method that will give me the time that the data was downloaded and cached, so that I can display some text in the form of "Last updated x minutes ago".

I've had a look at the arguments of OpenReadCompletedEventHandler but I can't find anything that relates to the age of the cached data. Is there any other way to do this, or is there any way to detect how data was retrieved (either from the server or from the cache) so I can record a last update time myself?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around this by adding a random parameter to the URL to bypass the WebClient cache, and then implementing my own caching system by storing data in Isolated Storage. This means that I can easily keep track of when data was last retrieved from the server. If I deem the data too old I can trigger a download from the server, otherwise the data is just fetched from either memory or Isolated Storage.